# Converting a Heikin Ashi related PineScript to MQL5

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, mql5, mql, metatrader5

The pinescript code is like the following

```
ha = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha, res, close[1])
ma = ema(ha_close[1], 30)
```

I'm trying to use the above code in MetaTrader5.

So I tried the following,

[ Using https://www.mql5.com/en/code/33 for getting Heikin Ashi values ]

```
int handleHA = iCustom(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,"Heiken Ashi");
```

Then I got the CLOSE buffer value, Which is at the 4th position,

```
double haArray[];
CopyBuffer(handleHA,3,1,5,haArray);
```

And then I got the EMA of those CLOSE values,

```
int handleEMA = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,30,0,MODE_EMA,haArray[1]);
CopyBuffer(handleEMA,0,1,5,emaArray);
```

But in Metatrader 5 I'm getting different results compared to the TradingView. I think I did the first and third step right. But I have doubts on how I wrote `ha_close = security(ha, res, close[1])` in MQL5. Need help :(